# Redirect https .com to https .co.uk without a valid SSL cert on .com without DNS change

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I have an SSL cert valid for the `www.` and `.` subdomains on a domain. That's up and working great. All traffic on `http` redirects to `https`, and all bare domain traffic redirects to the `www.` version. In short, everything ends up on `https://www.` So far so good.

However, I also have a .`com`. That currently has an apache level redirect (can't change DNS currently)

At the moment going to the `https://www.***.com` address shows that the certificate isn't valid, which is of course correct – it's only for `www` and `.` on `.co.uk`.

**Question**

How do I get the `https://www.***.com` to redirect to `https://www.***.co.uk` without a valid SSL cert for the .com, and without changing the DNS?

---

**Technical details**

All domains point to same server. A vhost is set up for the ssl version and non ssl version, both with aliases for www and no www for the .co.uk and .com.

A rewrite rule like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

pushes everything to https.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't send redirects without a vlid certificate. The redirect is done in either the HTTP protocol by returning a 301 or 302 response, or in html content with a meta header. For this data to be sent, the SSL connection needs to be set up first, with a valid certificate. So don't be ridiculously cheap and get an almost-free startssl certificate for the .com.

And if you don't want to point that domain to a separate IP, you need to set up [SNI support](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI) in apache to deal with multiple certs on one IP.

Comment: OK, this is what I thought. It's not me being cheap, I just don't want to recommend purchases that aren't required. Assumedly I can do that at DNS level without issue?

Comment: You can't do redirects at DNS level. What you do at DNS level is just tell browsers what IP they need to contact for your .com domain, and this can be of course the same IP as your .co.uk domain. But you will still need a certificate for you .com domain. The only thing that changes is what server you will have to install it on.